# Do not track Email opens and clicks

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I give subscribers the possibility to just opt-out from Email Tracking (opens, clicks, etc.), not from receiving Emails?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: I don't think this is possible without filtering out your audience and doing separate sends for every email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a preference Attribute called DoNotTrack and populate it on the subscriber. Which action you use to populate it, is in your hands.

To the Comment of Data Kid:

[Release Notes for Email Studio (DoNotTrack)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2018_email_studio.htm&type=5)

*Do Not Track Opens and Clicks
For Consent Management, we've introduced Do Not Track functionality in emails where we've added a send time check that honors the subscriber's preference attribute and suppresses their email opens and clicks. Create the preference attribute called DoNotTrack. Use this exact name and individually enable the attribute on each subscriber that does not want to be tracked. Review more details for data protection and privacy.*

[Consent Management for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=consent_management_marketing.htm&type=5)

*Create a mechanism for receiving a Do Not Track request, such as a preference center.
Use the DoNotTrack preference attribute to suppress subscriber-level events, such as opens, clicks, and replies.
This process does not affect messages or tracking sent before the Do Not Track request.*

Comment: How does this stop their clicks and opens from been tracked in data views?

Comment: Edited my answer above to answer your question - Its an internal marketing cloud mechanism.